# How can I make the height of div as large as possible?

Tags: html, css

I have written the HTML code like this:

```html
<div id="FirstDiv"></div>
<div id="SecondDiv"></div>
<div id="TARGETDIV"></div>
```

And CSS code like this:

```css
#FirstDiv {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50px;
}

#SecondDiv {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 230px;
}

#TARGETDIV {
  width: 100vw;
  height: /* What code should be here? */;
}
```

I have already set the height of `FirstDiv` and `SecondDiv`, and I want to make the `TARGETDIV` height as large as possible to fit the user's screen size. 
How can I write CSS code like that?

Comment: Consider using a flex box

Comment: set height:100vh;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modern way would probably be to use a flexbox and put a flex-grow on the target div. Using the CSS `calc` function like others said also works, but isn't dynamic

(On StackOverflow you have to click on the "Full Page" link after pressing "Run" to be able to see it)

```css
body {
  margin: 0; /* removes spacing outside page */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh; /* make body screen height */
}

#FirstDiv {
  background: green;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50px;
}

#SecondDiv {
  background: red;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 230px;
}

#TARGETDIV {
  flex-grow: 1; /* Set flex grow so the div takes up remaining space */
  background: blue;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="FirstDiv"></div>
  <div id="SecondDiv"></div>
  <div id="TARGETDIV"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `vh` unit and `calc` in your `height` setting:

```
height: calc(100vh - 230px - 50px);
```

Meaning: Full viewport height minus heights of the other two divs:

(Note: View the snippet in full page view to see the correct result - the first two divs together are already higher than the snippet window)

```css
html, body {
margin: 0;
}
#FirstDiv {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  
}

#SecondDiv {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 230px;
  background: red;
}

#TARGETDIV {
  width: 100vw;
  height: calc(100vh - 230px - 50px);
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="FirstDiv"></div>
<div id="SecondDiv"></div>
<div id="TARGETDIV"></div>
```